# Nav2 Cart/Shelf Pick

Tags: ros2, nav2

Just starting with Nav2, and curious if there is any example on picking carts after reaching pose from under without being detecting as obstacle ? (Was considering about retro-reflectors on carts)

Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times I've seen this done, the robot uses the navigation stack to get "close" to the cart (usually a designated pose in front of the cart), and then uses a custom perception + control loop to actually "dock" with the cart.

There has been a [long-standing ticket](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/1975) aimed at a more generic docking controller for Nav2 - but as of yet, no real progress. That ticket does have lots of resources around docking control algorithms (and pointers to some possible open source implementations that might be a starting point for you).

Comment: Thank you ! Appreciate it.

Comment: +1, this is the correct way to think about it.